# how to make a file based user login page

Tags: php, file, cookies, login-page

this thing really blown my mind up i want to design a page with a text box where my clients can enter their username  and by using php i want to tell the page to check if there is a username such as that in a file named locationn.html if existed create a cookie and let him in another page if not add a new line to the file containing the user name entered.

this is my code in this code "unamec" is the name of the cookie and "$user" is the user name and "umname" is the name of the username text box which its value is sent to the page itself using a post method.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["uname"])){
$user=$_POST["uname"];
$pass=$_POST["passs"];
$see=file_get_contents("locationn.html");
$lines=explode("\n",$see);
foreach($lines as $line){
if($line == $user){
setcookie("unamec",$user,time()+86400,"/");
echo '<script>window.location="main.html";</script>';
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: In general this certainly is possible. Although the question arises: _why?_ Usually a database is used for such thing, a database approach is much faster and much more flexible than using a text file as a storage backend.

Comment: A side note: take a look at php's `file()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php It saves you the manual `explode()`, since you already get the lines separated into an array.

Comment: sure but thats better for someone who knows sql or stuff @Epodax

Comment: ? What? I still don't see a question

Comment: yes but then i have to open the file by fopen() so then writing on it would be harder but thanks i will try this @arkascha

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there. To write the file you have to `fopen()` it anyway, that is completely independent from reading it. There is no difference. My suggestion just simplifies the reading which often will be the sole file access required (since the user already exists).

Comment: what the problem with this code? although i have the username saved in a single line it still doesn't let me in. in fact if i add the code to write the username in the file it adds it again. @Epodax

Comment: i tried what you sayed but seems like it cannot find the directory

Comment: this is the error code:Warning: fopen(/home/u704165960/public_html/locationn,html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u704165960/public_html/default (1).php on line 29   @arkascha

Comment: Sorry: can't help you with that. 1. you don't show the `fopen()` command, so there is nothing I can say about it and 2. the error message is speaking for itself: you try to open a file that does not exist.

Comment: Looks like you have a comma in the file name in your error message.

Comment: yeah thanks @Progrock

Comment: what such a concentration !! @Progrock

Comment: good news problem solved i just needed to trim both of the variables you can use my experience question is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with the storage and retrieval of a username from a file. You could adapt this and couple with session management, to achieve your aims.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    if($username !== preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $username))
        throw new Exception('Invalid username.');
    $userStore = new UserStore('/tmp/creds.txt');
    if(! $userStore->isStored($username)) {
        if($userStore->storeUsername($username)) {
            echo $username . ' stored.';
        }
    } else {
        echo $username . ' is on file.';
    }
}


class userStore
{
    public $fp;
    public $filename;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        if(!file_exists($this->filename))
            file_put_contents($this->filename, null);
        $this->fp = fopen($this->filename, "r+");
    }

    public function isStored($username) {
        $username_exists = false;

        if(! $size = filesize($this->filename))
            return false;
        $contents  = fread($this->fp, $size);

        $lines = array_filter(explode("\n", $contents));
        foreach($lines as $line) {
            if(trim($line) == $username) {
                $username_exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $username_exists;
    }

    public function storeUsername($username)
    {
        $fp = $this->fp;
        if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
            fwrite($fp, "$username\n");
            fflush($fp);
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
?>
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username'>
    <input type='submit' value='login'>
</form>
```

Comment: i got the idea to trim my variables from your code thanks